# Getting the Parent object in nested XML to Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, nested-class

Assume two classes, simplified

```
Class Room {
    String Name {get; set;}
    String Type {get;set;}
    List<Employee> Employees {get; set;}
}
Class Employee {
    Int64 ID {get;set;}
    Room Parent {get; set;}
}
```

I get XML data from a database and use LINQ to read this XML into objects:

```
List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();
rooms = 
    (
        from r in XDocument.Load(reader).Root.Elements("Room") select new Room {
            Name = r.Attribute("name").Value,
            Type = r.Attribute("type").Value,
            Employees = 
                (
                    from e in r.Elements("Employee") select new Employee {
                    ID = (Int64)e.Attribute("hrid"),
                    Parent = ?????
                }
            ).ToList()
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Notice the ?????? up there? That's the question. How can I create a reference to the parent Room within the Employee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the best practice but you can set null for parent or just discard first. And after created your list, you can iterate through rooms and set employee parents.

```
foreach (var room in rooms)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < room.Employees.Count; i++)
    {
        room.Employees[i].Parent = room;
    }
}
```